# installation of firebug in Firefox 21 version

Tags: javascript

Hi I have Firefox 21 verion browser, but i am not able to use my firebug that i installed before. Can anyone tell me which version of firebug will support for the above version ? I am not able to run my program because of this issue.

Comment: See answer below and do some research before asking question please!

Answer (score 1):

Firebug 1.11 is supported version from Firefox 17.0 to Firefox 22.0, please take a look: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Compatibility table:

```
Firefox 3.6 with Firebug 1.7.3
Firefox 4.0 with Firebug 1.7.3
Firefox 5.0 with Firebug 1.8.2 (and also Firebug 1.7.3)
Firefox 6.0 with Firebug 1.8.2 (and also Firebug 1.9)
Firefox 7.0 with Firebug 1.8.2 (and also Firebug 1.9)
Firefox 8.0 with Firebug 1.8.3 (and also Firebug 1.9)
Firefox 9.0 with Firebug 1.8.4 (and also Firebug 1.9)
Firefox 10.0 with Firebug 1.9
Firefox 11.0 with Firebug 1.9
Firefox 12.0 with Firebug 1.9
Firefox 13.0 with Firebug 1.10 (and also Firebug 1.9)
Firefox 14.0 with Firebug 1.10
Firefox 15.0 with Firebug 1.10
Firefox 16.0 with Firebug 1.10
Firefox 17.0 with Firebug 1.11 (and also Firebug 1.10)
Firefox 18.0 with Firebug 1.11
Firefox 19.0 with Firebug 1.11
Firefox 20.0 with Firebug 1.11
Firefox 21.0 with Firebug 1.11
Firefox 22.0 with Firebug 1.11
Firefox 23.0 with Firebug 1.12 (and also Firebug 1.11)
Firefox 24.0 with Firebug 1.12
Firefox 25.0 with Firebug 1.12
Firefox 26.0 with Firebug 1.12
Firefox 27.0 with Firebug 1.12
Firefox 28.0 with Firebug 1.12
Firefox 29.0 with Firebug 1.12
Firefox 30.0 with Firebug 2.0 (and also Firebug 1.12)
Firefox 31.0 with Firebug 2.0 (and also Firebug 1.12)
Firefox 32.0 with Firebug 2.0 (and also Firebug 1.12)
Firefox 33 - 46 with Firebug 2.0
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for replay. I already tried for the same link but it showing that it not supported on Firefox 21 version. Can you share the exart link to download the same?

Comment: Are you sure you are installing Firebug 1.11 and Firefox is 21?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the exact firebug for you: https://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.11/

```
firebug-1.11.0.xpi      18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.0M  
firebug-1.11.0a1.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  1.5M  
firebug-1.11.0a2.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  1.5M  
firebug-1.11.0a3.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  1.5M  
firebug-1.11.0a4.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  1.5M  
firebug-1.11.0a5.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.0M  
firebug-1.11.0a6.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.0M  
firebug-1.11.0b1.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.0M  
firebug-1.11.0b2.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.0M  
firebug-1.11.0b3.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.0M  
firebug-1.11.0b4.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.1M  
firebug-1.11.1.xpi      18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.1M  
firebug-1.11.1b1.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.1M  
firebug-1.11.2.xpi      18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.1M  
firebug-1.11.2b1.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.1M  
firebug-1.11.2b2.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.1M  
firebug-1.11.3.xpi      18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.1M  
firebug-1.11.3b1.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.1M  
firebug-1.11.4.xpi      18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.1M  
firebug-1.11.4b1.xpi    18-Dec-2014 21:24  2.1M  
update.rdf              18-Dec-2014 21:24  889
```